# How to escape letters in Angular Date pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to ask something might already exists here on SO. However none of them really helped me so far. So I decided you ask this question in order to hopefully find an answer to it:

I want to put in the format as string and escape the `h` letter as you can see, but for some reason this does not work and it shows me a number.

```
<span>{{ comment?.last_modified_at | date : 'MMM d · HH:mm U\hr' }}</span>
```

- Shows: Jul 6 · 14:03 U2r
- Expected: Jul 6 · 14:03 Uhr

I need this format string as a whole and cannot put it outside or any other manipulation of the date afterwards.

Hope you can help. Thanks a lot for your understanding.

Sources: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: And, what format you want the date to comeup ?

Comment: `Jul 6 · 14:03 Uhr` instead of `Jul 6 · 14:03 U2r`

Comment: You can do it like this: `<span>{{ comment?.last_modified_at | date : 'MMM d · HH:mm' }}hr</span>`

Comment: did you try U\\hr ?

Comment: where the 2 come from ?  and if you want to escape the 'h' why are you expecting it ?

Comment: form what i see the expected should be Ur ? no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code to the following ::

```
<span>{{comment?.last_modified_at | date : 'MMM d · HH:mm U\'h\'r' }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{comment?.last_modified_at | date: 'HH:mm:ss \'Uhr\'' }}` gives you the expected output and keeps the term "Uhr" (which means "o clock" in German) readable / searchable in the code.